# What happens to the d/dr term of the continuity equation in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mass

The derivation of the continuity equation in cyclindrical coordinates should look like this,

$$ \dfrac{dm_{cv}}{dt}=\sum \dot{m}_{in} - \sum \dot{m}_{out} $$

where
$$ m_{cv} = \rho r \Delta\theta\Delta r \Delta z $$
$$ \dot{m} = \rho u A $$

I'm observing only the radial direction, meaning that the velocity in $\theta$ and $z$ direction is zero ($u_{\theta}=0, u_{z}=0$). So,

$$\dot{m}_{in} = \rho u_{r} \times r \Delta\theta \Delta z$$
$$ \dot{m}_{out} = [\rho u_{r} + \Delta(\rho u_{r})] \times (r+\Delta r)\Delta\theta\Delta z $$

Without further ado,

$$ \dfrac{d(\rho r \Delta\theta\Delta r \Delta z)}{dt} = \dot{m}_{in} - \dot{m}_{out} $$

$$ \dfrac{d(\rho r \Delta\theta\Delta r \Delta z)}{dt} = \rho u_{r} \times r \Delta\theta \Delta z - [\rho u_{r} + \Delta(\rho u_{r})] \times (r+\Delta r)\Delta\theta\Delta z $$
$$ r \Delta\theta\Delta r \Delta z \dfrac{d\rho}{dt} = [r \rho u_{r} - (\rho u_{r} + \Delta(\rho u_{r}))(r+\Delta r)] \Delta\theta \Delta z $$

Dividing both sides with $ \Delta\theta \Delta z $,
$$ r\Delta r \dfrac{d\rho}{dt} = [r \rho u_{r} - (\rho u_{r} + \Delta(\rho u_{r}))(r+\Delta r)] $$
$$ r \Delta r \dfrac{d\rho}{dt} = r\rho u_{r} - r \rho u_{r} - \rho u_{r}\Delta r - r\Delta(\rho u_{r}) - \Delta(\rho u_{r})\Delta r $$

Dividing both sides with $ r\Delta r $,
$$ \dfrac{d\rho}{dt} = -\dfrac{\rho u_{r}\Delta r}{r\Delta r} - \dfrac{r \Delta(\rho u_{r})}{r\Delta r} - \dfrac{\Delta(\rho u_{r})\Delta r}{r\Delta r} $$

Because the first two terms on the right-hand side follows the product rule,
$$ \dfrac{d\rho}{dt} = -\dfrac{1}{r\Delta r}\Delta[(r)(\rho u_{r})] -\dfrac{\Delta(\rho u_{r})\Delta r}{r\Delta r} $$

Finally, it can be put like this,
$$ \dfrac{d\rho}{dt} = -\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{d(r\rho u_{r})}{dr} - \dfrac{\Delta(\rho u_{r})\Delta r}{r\Delta r} $$

But what happens to the $ \dfrac{\Delta(\rho u_{r})\Delta r}{r\Delta r} $ term? Why does it get omitted in the textbooks?

[image]

Comment: What are your $\Delta$? Are you trying to do calculus without proper treatment of infinitesimals? The differential form in cylindric coordinates follows purely abstractly from [the form of del in cylindrical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates).

Comment: I don't understand. Excuse my newbie self. But I thought $\Delta x$ becomes $dx$ if $\Delta x$ approaches zero. So, I could have written $ \dfrac{d(\rho u_{r}) dr}{r dr} $ there. But I thought it's just a matter of notation.

Comment: Solved. I forgot to consider the change in surface area in $r$-direction. I wrote $ [\rho u_{r} + \Delta(\rho u_{r})] \times (r+\Delta r)\Delta\theta\Delta z $ instead of $ \rho u_{r} r \Delta\theta \Delta z + \Delta(\rho u_{r} r \Delta\theta \Delta z) $. I should have considered the change in surface area as well.